# C++ generic programming CRTP base class inherit from class provided by derived type

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Going through Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language", 4th ed. There is some sample code in 27.4.1 Composing Data Structures that I can't figure out. The problem occurs using a type alias in the Base class that is provided by the Derived class (CRTP pattern) via template parameter.

```
 1 #include <vector>
 2 using namespace std;
 3 struct Red_black_balance {};
 4 template<typename N>
 5 struct Node_base : N::balance_type { //<==
 6     N* left_child;
 7     N* right_child;
 8     Node_base() { }
 9 };
10 template<typename Val, typename Balance>
11 struct Search_node : Node_base<Search_node<Val, Balance>>
12 {
13    using balance_type = Balance; // <==
14    Val val;
15    Search_node(Val v): val(v) {}
16 };
17 template<typename T>
18 using Rb_node = Search_node<T, Red_black_balance>; 
19 using My_node = Rb_node<double>;
20 int main(int, char **)
21 {
22    My_node my_root(0.0);
23    return 0;
24 }
```

Here is the compiler output (g++ version 4.9.2):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -o test15 test15.cpp
test15.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Node_base<Search_node<double, Red_black_balance> >’:
test15.cpp:11:8:   required from ‘struct Search_node<double, Red_black_balance>’
test15.cpp:22:17:   required from here
test15.cpp:5:8: error: no type named ‘balance_type’ in ‘struct Search_node<double, Red_black_balance>’
 struct Node_base : N::balance_type {
        ^
```

As I understand it, when the template instantiation is done in main(), all the template dependent types should be generated based on the information at that point (unlike non-dependent types which get instantiated at the point of template definition). So the compiler should know what N::balance_type corresponds to when generating the Node_base instance in main, right? But it does not appear to. Any idea what is wrong in the code?

Comment: `struct Node_base : typename N::balance_type`?

Comment: Nope - tried that
    $ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -o test15 test15.cpp
    test15.cpp:5:20: error: keyword ‘typename’ not allowed in this context (the base class is implicitly a type)
 struct Node_base : typename N::balance_type {

Comment: @John *"A qualified name used as the name in a mem-initializer-id, a **base-specifier**, or an elaborated-type-specifier
     is implicitly assumed to name a type, without the use of the typename keyword."* [temp.res]/5

Answer (score 1):

It's effectively a circular dependency issue.

```
template<typename N>
struct Node_base : N::balance_type
```

In order to instantiate `Node_base<N>`, we need to first look at `N::balance_type`.

```
template<typename Val, typename Balance>
struct Search_node : Node_base<Search_node<Val, Balance>>
```

In order to instantiate `Search_node<Val, Balance>`, we need to first instantiate `Node_base<Search_node<Val, Balance>>`. Which requires instantiating `Search_node<Val, Balance>::balance_type`, which requires instantiating `Search_node<Val, Balance>`.

You could just pass `Balance` in separately:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Balance>
struct Node_base : Balance { .. };

template <typename Val, typename Balance>
struct Search_node : Node_base<Search_node<Val, Balance>, Balance> { .. };
```

Comment: The suggestion you make is what Stroustrup had originally used - and it works. His goal in the revised example was to remove one template parameter by using an implicit argument in the form of a type from the derived class. 
I don't actually follow your argument regarding circular dependency - wouldn't the same sort of dependency apply even in your working suggestion? Both Node_base and Search_node are dependent on each others definition???

Comment: @user1467962 Nope. `Node_base` has some `Derived*` members - which is fine with incomplete types. There's no other dependency on `Search_node`.

Comment: You're right. As soon as I added a non-pointer - got incomplete type error. With pointers, no instantiation is required. So there is no way to do what Stroustrup suggests should be possible?